# Xamarin.Forms Picker ItemDisplayBinding not working with static list

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I was experimenting with picker using different item sources and when i tried using a static list, i keep getting a NullPointerException.

**Xaml**

```
<Picker ItemsSource="{x:Static Member=stat:Stat.ItemModList}"
                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" />
```

The picker is the only element in the xaml. I didn't change the code behind file. stat is the namespace for the static list file.

When only `<Picker ItemsSource="{x:Static Member=stat:Stat.ItemModList}" />` is written the picker does work and the picker items are all displayed as `ItemMod` class' `ToString()` 

When I add the `ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}` it just does not work. I get the nullpointerexception when i click on the picker.

The other files:

**Stat.cs - Static List**

```
public static class Stat
    {
        public static List<ItemMod> ItemModList = new List<ItemMod>()
        {
            new ItemMod {Id = -1, Name = "Default"},
            new ItemMod {Id = 1, Name = "Item 1"},
            new ItemMod {Id = 2, Name = "Item 2"},
            new ItemMod {Id = 3, Name = "Item 3"},
            new ItemMod {Id = 4, Name = "Item 4"}
        };
    }
```

**ItemMod.cs**

```
public class ItemMod
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Name;
    }
```

Comment: `Name` must be a public property, not a field.  You can only bind to public properties

Comment: @Jason Thank you, can't believe i missed it. I was like yeah it is a property why isn't it working...didn't realize till i saw your post that I didn't add the get set bit

Comment: Since this is resolved, can you post and accept and answer? This way others don't bother opening this question as it will be marked "answered".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ItemDisplayBinding did not work as the BindingProperty `Name` was declared as a public field in the ItemMod class instead of a public property. 
So in ItemMod.cs it should be `public string Name {get;set;}`

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer , which will help more people .

Comment: This is exactly my problem. The picker list is still EMPTY. I think that was the question was all about. This accepted answer does not help for me and it actually serves a different purpose.